# Переход Между сценами Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при переходе на сцену с игрой, сцена главного меня остается открытой.
Скрипт перехода на сцену:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoadLevel : MonoBehaviour {

public Button LoadButton;

void Start()
{
    Button btn = LoadButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
}

void TaskOnClick()
{
    Debug.Log("Loading");
    Debug.Log("QuitingScene");
    Application.Quit(); //здесь пытаюсь закрыть сцену   
    LoadGame();
    Debug.Log("Load!!");
}

void LoadGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("main", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
}
}
```

Собственно вопрос:

> Можете помочь, подсказать или натолкнуть на то как закрыть предыдущую
>   сцену..

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.Quit();` — это дает сигнал выйти из приложения полностью, а-ка нажать на крестик в верхнем правом углу окна. А вот предыдущая сцена обычно автоматически "убивается" при загрузке новой. Так что в первую очередь нужно удалить `Application.Quit();`

И следует упомянуть о том, что при использовании `mode` в методе `LoadScene` надо бы тогда писать так:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("main", LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

т.к. согласно документации

- `Additive` — добавляет сцену к списку загруженных
- `Single` — закрывает все сцены и загружает данную.

Но как я понимаю ты можешь и без него обойтись, т.е. написать пока просто `SceneManager.LoadScene("main");`

Comment: Спасибо,завтра проверю)